# What is the advantages of creating hierarchy in SSAS?

Tags: ssas

What is the advantages of creating hierarchy in SSAS? What are the difference between drag and drop year,month one by one and single hierarchy on browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly:

- Aggregations: If you want the sum per year and you have 
  aggregations per month, SSAS will sum all the monthly aggregations
  instead of summing all the values on that particuallar year
- Its a Microsoft best practice to add big dimensions in some sort of
  hierarchy and set the AttributeHierarchyVisible property to false so
  the attribute is enable to be browsed through the hierarchy but not
  alone. That prevents the user of dragging a attribute with 1 million rows to the cube, which would break it

Answer (score 1):

The advantages of creating a Hierarchy is that you give your users (Cube Users) a pre defined hierarchy that will be common with all users. You will be saving them a lot of time instead of having to drag and drop 3 - 4 members every time. Additionally, if you are working with PPS or any other reporting layer, your filters can work directly on the Hierarchy to offer users 1 Filter with drill down options instead of having them choose from 3 to 4 Filters. Finally, if you use PPS, Hierarchies will allow the user to perform auto drill down in PPS charts.

These are just a few of the benefits of Hierarchies, there are also some benefits related to Performance of Aggregations, More flexibility when working with Date Hierarchies and creating custom measures.